# Using SEO in React JS

Tags: reactjs, seo

I want to use React JS for my blog website. Is this possible?
SEO is important for me.

Answer (score 1):

U can use [nextjs](https://nextjs.org/). It a framework for SEO web reactjs.
It includes server side render (SSR), ...

Answer (score 1):

As @Thanh Ngo said, you can use [Nextjs](https://nextjs.org/)

But you can also create a server inside your project. Create a directory inside your project "server" and create a new directory "views". You can use [Expressjs](https://expressjs.com/) or another one. Take a template engine like [Pugjs](https://pugjs.org/).
Now you're ready to do SEO with React. In your browser, go to the "network conditions" tab and remove checkbox "select automatically" and select "googlebot". You're now ready :)

If you don't understand something in my explanations tell me :)

Comment: thank you , actually i want to know is it correct use react.js for blog website or it uses for panel admin and ...

Comment: According to me, yes. You should go to https://www.gatsbyjs.org/starters/?v=2 I think you're gonna like it

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you can use react-helmet. that can create many meta tag dynamic SEO. It's very useful with google seo